# Factory Girl Saving to Development Database (Guard Issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm on **Rails 3.2** and have my gemfile set up like this:

```
# Testing Gems
gem "factory_girl_rails", :group => :test

group :development, :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "ruby_gntp", :require => false
  gem "addressable"
  gem "launchy"
end
```

However, Factory Girl **insists** on saving testing records to my development database rather than the testing database.  **Note that I am using guard to run the tests via the shell.**

Here's what's in my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I know my question is similar to this one: [Factory girl saving records in my development database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208358/factory-girl-saving-records-in-my-development-database) but I'm doing everything he did and it still isn't working for me.

I have also run `bundle update`, `bundle install`, `bundle install --without test` and then `bundle install` again.  I originally thought it was a Gemfile.lock issue but everything I do to update that has no effect.

Anyone have any ideas?

### Update

All my factories are using the development.sqlite3 database, but here's an example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :saddle, :class => Saddle do
        name            "Carlton"
        saddle_category_id  2
        description     "This is a saddle description"
        details         "Saddle details will go here!"
        best_uses       "List of best uses should go here."
        price           3025.00
    end
end
```

The test code that saves to my database is simply `saddle = Factory(:saddle)`.

Comment: Can you add the test code that executes the save (that persists to your test db)?

Comment: I even have `factory_girl_rails` in my `group :development, :test` to quickly test out factories during `rails c -s` and so far no issues..

Comment: @kain, are you using guard to run your specs?  I'm thinking guard is setting the environment to development now.

Comment: Just tried `rails c -s`.  It opened up in the development environment.  I then tested `saddle = Factory(:saddle)`.  It errors out saying `undefined method 'Factory'`, indicating that FactoryGirl isn't being loaded in the development environment—which is how it should be; but it still saves to the development environment when guard runs it.  Weird.

Comment: it is FactoryGirl.create, and yes, I'm using guard, spork, rspec, factorygirl combo

Comment: make sure you have ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test' in spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

You have the same issue. Look at your Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
```

It's loading all those gems for `:test` as well. Remove that part and you should be good to go.

Comment: Tried that and ran `bundle update` to update the `Gemfile.lock` file.  The problem continues.

Comment: This may sound silly, but I've had weird issues before where this solved it: try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and then simply run `bundle`.

Comment: Yeah, it was worth a try but didn't solve the problem.  See my comment on Teddy's answer: it looks like guard is causing the problem by running in development. `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec guard` works, but I shouldn't have to tell guard to run in test mode, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the `RAILS_ENV` in your command line:

```
rake test RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: When I try that, I get this error: `DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases,simply use Ruby memoization pattern instead. (called from <top (required)> at ~/path-to-app/config/environment.rb:5)`  

Rake then aborts.

Comment: I tried starting guard like this: `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec guard` and guard ran my tests in the test environment like it should.  I shouldn't have to specify the environment though, right?  One would think guard would know...

Comment: I guess you shouldn't have to do this, but it is easier to add it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

As I see You've got the answer [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/93). And the issue was in using `==` instead of `=`.

I just faced with the similar issue (Rspec 3). As you know there is the file `spec/rails_helper.rb` and a string `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'` inside. First I thought that it's already set with wrong value and tried to replace it with `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'` but it didn't help me.

Then I moved this string to `spec/spec_helper.rb` and it works properly. I can't explain this behavior yet but it works.