# FactoryGirl sequence generating same email in database repeatedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am using the following code to generate an email address:

```
sequence :email do |n|
  "person#{n}@example.com"
end
```

Then to generate a user, I use the following code:

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) {|n| "person#{n}"}
  email { generate :email }
  password 'password'
  password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
end
```

However, when I run the test, it always generates "person1@example.com". It never increases to '2'.

I get the error message "person1@example.com" already exists in the database.

How do I get FactoryGirl to increment up?

Comment: what happens if you use it as an attribute? `factory(:user){email}`

Comment: How do you do that? I tried to add another factory(:user) with only 'email' but but I got an error message saying TOP => test:integration => test:prepare => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment

Comment: I'm referring to the Get Started file in the FactoryGirl github repository: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences

Comment: Same problem. I think it's because it's an integration test so it actually saves to the live database. I'm not sure how FactoryGirl would even know where to start sequencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this message when generating users within single test, then yes, it's the problem with generating unique emails. But you can receive that kind of error message because of test database not being clean (user left over from a former test). If in doubt, check test log.

Comment: Ok so the problem was not with the test database but with the live database because it actually saves to the real database during the signup process because it is an integration test. I guess there's no fix for that.

Comment: You've lost me there. What you mean "live database"? There are usually test, development and production databases. And it's not clear from your question whether it's an integration test or not but why does it matter? It's FactoryGirl, it writes to database. If you don't want to you should use some kind of mock or whatever.

Comment: I meant development database. For example when I run an integration test using FactoryGirl to test creating a new user, it will create a new user named 'person1@example.com'. The next time I run another integration test, it will also try to create a new user 'person1@example.com' but the test won't work since it won't let me save the same email to the database. So how would I get FactoryGirl to know there is already a 'person1@example.com' in the database so FactoryGirl will know it should start the sequence at '2' instead of '1' ie 'person2@example.com'.

Comment: That's weird. Which database to write to is determined by RAILS_ENV variable. The first thing all test helpers do is set up RAILS_ENV like this `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'`. I guess there is something really wrong with your test setup. Having tests leave some data in the test database is another thing. Means probably you just turned off `use_transactional_fixtures`. In any case you have to get your test setup fixed.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I use Capybara with Selenium so maybe that's why it saves to the development database, not the test database. And Selenium does not work with transactional fixtures. In test_helper it says 'Transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium tests, because Capybara uses a separate server thread, which the transactions would be hidden from. We hence use DatabaseCleaner to truncate our test database.' But it still seems like the integration test should save to the test database.

Comment: I tried moving the FactoryGirl gem in the gemfile to a separate :test group too (currently in group :test, :development) per this other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208358/factory-girl-saving-records-in-my-development-database but it's still saving to the development databse.

Comment: I tried rake test RAILS_ENV=test and it still saved to the development database.

Comment: Should be the other way around `RAILS_ENV=test rake test` - you set the environment variable and then run the command. May be rake works both ways, I'm not sure. If RAILS_ENV is set to test and the test still writes to development database then your `database.yml` is messed up I guess. I just don't see any other way. You sure it writes to dev database? You can run `RAILS_ENV='test' rails c`, make sure `Rails.env` is 'test' and check which database is connected. Integration or not a test should not touch development database.